# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. Three.js TrackballControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a 3D application using Three.js. In this application I need to have control system with the camera. I'm using TrackballControlls for this control system. But when I add an event listener there is a weird error: `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.` it contains a link to: [this chromium website](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312)

I understand the error, but is there a way to work around this error? This error comes from this line: `event.preventDefault();`

**Some code:**

```
var control = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
control.addEventListener("change", render);

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function update() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    control.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it actually a warning?

Comment: @Teemu That could be the case.

Comment: There's a big difference between a warning and an error, warnings are not breaking the script execution as errors are.

Comment: Where is the line `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @Teemu It is indeed a warning...

Comment: @Kaiido It is in TrackballControls.

Comment: three.js had [a related issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10373) a few years ago, but at that time, they apparently didn't understand clearly what were passive event listeners and closed it. Now that wheel event listeners attache to `document` are treated as passive, they'll actually have to implement it. I left a comment on the issue to this regard.

Comment: The warning is telling you `preventDefault` did nothing because the event is passive. If you actually need `preventDefault` to work then you need to make the event listener non-passive as in `someElement.addEventListener('someevent', listenerFunction, {passive: false})`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, my application works. But the warning is pretty annoying sometimes. I hope they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is a warning. This cannot hurt the web application.

But it's kinda annoying. You can turn this warning off, by using this method:

Instead of using this:

```
control.addEventListener("change", render);
```

put this inside the code:

```
control.addEventListener("change", render, { passive: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

> var control = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

Please create `TrackballControls` always like so:

```
var control = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

There is a new PR that will make the second parameter of `TrackballControls` mandatory and prevent `document` as an argument.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17612

`three.js R109`

Comment: Done!, But why is this nescersary?

Comment: We encountered some issue with using `document` in camera controls. Applying the canvas element of `WebGLRenderer` makes the implementation of controls a bit easier and avoids edge cases like this one: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17612/files#diff-ffef32863dd826c87a45cfb28c4ddd83L673

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. I didn't encounter any problems without the domElement. But i'll use it.

Comment: Fast reading your PR it seems you are only looking for `if( domElement === document )` but passing `window` or `document.body` would produce the same outcome. Not sure how much you want to prevent this case and be strict there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! TBH, I've never seen that devs pass in `window` or `document.body`. Since `document` was the default so far, I've added only a check for this case. We can still enhance the checks later if necessary.